# Towards the end of Game of Thrones season 7, has Drogon become larger than Balerion was?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

Daenerys Targaryen's dragons gradually increase in size over the course of Game of Thrones (the TV series), and Drogon seems to be the largest.

At the end of season 7 (episodes 6 or 7, shouldn't matter really), how does Drogon's size compare to [Balerion the black dread](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Balerion), Aegon I's dragon? Also, is its growth known to have/have not stopped?

Comment: We don't really have a size for Drogon to be sure.

Comment: @Edlothiad: We see him all the time, what's not to be sure about?

Comment: @Edlothiad Use men for reference. Jaime is standing next to the skull. Daenerys is standing next to Drogon. Daenerys is a bit shorter than Jaime. We can make an assumption based on that reference

Comment: @Aegon how tall is Jaime compared to Daenerys? Do we use they're IRL heights or in-show heights?

Comment: @Edlothiad IRL Height wouldn't be that different from show height I assume?

Comment: What if Balerion had a particularly small head?

Comment: @Edlothiad You mean drogon? Idk, That's why I deleted the answer here. It's easier to answer from the books rather than stumbling about for Show answer. But logically Drogon should be smaller as he is just a few years old while Balerion was two centuries old.

Comment: According to [Thrones Facts tweet from yesterday](https://twitter.com/thronesfacts/status/899427427033636865), Balerion is **a LOT** bigger than Drogon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Balerion seems to be bigger - just compare the skull of Balerion to the head of Drogon:

[image: Cersei next to Balerion skull]
*Cersei next to Balerion skull*

[image: Jon next to Drogon]
*Jon next to Drogon*

But keep in mind that Balerion is much older than Drogon, as he lived for two centuries, so maybe Drogon will keep growing and become larger than Balerion.

EDIT : Here is a video (credits to ABcDexter who linked it [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168025/how-old-are-danaeryss-dragons/168026?noredirect=1#comment448354_168026) ) that cover the same question. bonus point for using Daenerys as SI for length

Comment: He looks like he's 2 or 3 times bigger. The skull is one Jon long. If Cersei is ~6 inches shorter than Jon (remember Jon is small). Balerion's head looks at least 2-3 Cersei's long

Comment: 1/2 Jon high, compared to 1.5-2 Cerseis

Comment: Note that Kit is 1.73m tall and Lena is 1.66 but that's not a lot of diff so Balerion is much bigger

Comment: Plus, as dragons seem to be 3D, if we double the size (height, width and length), the total volume is multiplied by 8. If we consider he is 3 times larger, the total volume is multiplied by 27. that's quite a lot

Comment: @Kepotx Seem to be 3D or are? A 2D dragon wouldn't be much use.

Comment: [This is Balerion from TWOIAF depiction](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/images/d/d4/Aegon_on_Balerion.jpg), see the size of Aegon I compared to his dragon

Comment: @Aegon I didn't want to use book description as he asked for the show and we have a good reference point, but the fact remain the same : Balerion is HUGE. plus, he had an armor

Comment: @Kepotx No problems that's why I commented it, for people who might be interested, instead of answering

Comment: 3D dragons? These people have middle-ages-level technology, the dragons are 2D at best.

Comment: @Kepotx: You're not wrong, but the question wasn't about Drogon and Balerion's volume. When speaking of size, we generally refer to a one-dimensional factor _k_, where _k_ is the **scale** between the two objects that are being compared. Comparing (two lines/two squares with a length/two cubes with an edge length) of 1cm and 2cm are all considered to be **twice the size** (i.e. the scale factor _k_ = 2), even though the surface area quadruples and the volume octuples. Size does not colloquially denote surface area, nor volume, but rather the **scale factor**.