# How old are Danaerys's dragons?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

This is a follow-up question to the following line in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/168016/53012)

> Note that Dany's dragons are still very young only a few years old.

**How old are Dany's dragons exactly?** And if their age is considered 'young' for dragons, what is the normal age of an adult dragon?

From the [wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons):

> For generations, the dragon-kings ruled over much of Westeros - but
>   the dragons eventually died out after nearly a century and a half, and
>   the species was subsequently considered to be extinct, the oldest
>   dragon Vhagar living up to 181 years.

So, the normal age should be close to that. Maybe 120 or so.

Comment: Where's @Aegon when you need him!?

Comment: They’re seven seasons old, aren’t they?

Comment: @Darren *6. They were born at the end of season one's last episode.

Comment: @Darren I'm always skeptical about the time thing in GoT. Really need to start with the books :D

Comment: Going with the books can be hard as years in fantasy novels are primarily based around the seasons, and since they have a very strange and irregular season cycle, and I don't remember them mentioning solstices or equinoxes, it is a little ambiguous.

Comment: @Daishozen: “years in fantasy novels are primarily based around the seasons” — [They’re not in *A Song of Ice and Fire*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59195/440).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Correct, but white it has admittedly been a couple years since I read the novels, I don't recall what they use to measure the years at all. I was trying to point out that we can't use the normal way of determining years.

Comment: @Daishozen: well, as stated in the answers to that question, the “normal” way to determine years is to measure rotations round the sun, and it seems that they do that in Westeros like we do (hence they know how many years each summer and winter lasts).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thanks, I was unaware of that quote from GRRM, that helps a lot.

Answer (score 7):

According to the same wiki, [they are 6 years old](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Drogon), but I would not blindly believe this wiki, as they present Vhagar the oldest of dragons, even if [Balerion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Balerion) is 220 years old. According to [this timeline](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest#Year_299_After_the_Conquest), (taken from the books, so it may change a little bit), Dany's dragons are born in 299AC(After Conquest), and ADWD take place in 300AD. To have a good answer to this question, we must know the time lapse between end of season 1 and today.

Edit : (credit to @TheLethalCoder) 
[According to gameofthrones.wikia.com timeline](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline), 1 season = 1 year in-universe, but I personally think that it's just an easy option which doesn't represent reality.

Comment: I think they get 6 years from the six seasons after their birth but I'm not sure how accurate that information is.

Comment: 220?  And Drogon is just 7 yrs old!  Imagining the havoc he is already raising for his age, wonder what facing Balerion felt like :D

Comment: @Dawny33 Drogon is said to be Balerion reincarnate so probably similar.

Comment: “According to gameofthrones.wikia.com timeline, 1 season = 1 year in-universe, but I personally think that it's just an easy option which doesn't represent reality.” — Possibly, although this season characters have been referring to events from earlier seasons as happening “years ago”, so we know multiple years are meant to have passed in-universe since the start of the show.

Comment: In the books it's definitely slower. All of the events of seasons 3 and 4, and parts of season 2 and 5, happen in less than a year (at least those that take place in King's Landing).

Comment: [Balerion was HUGE!! Drogon would be HUMONGOUS!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q7_37YcvKs)